# java JFrame resize

Tags: java, swing, jframe, componentlistener

I have the following code segment in my project.

```
someJFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){  
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    pane.resize(new Dimension(getSize().width/5, getSize().height/3));
    pane.revalidate();
    pane.repaint();
    }
});
```

It seems to call the componentResized() method right at the beginning when the JFrame is initialized for the first time, even though the user did not resize the JFrame- I need to prevent this from happening. I only want componetResized() to be called when a real resize has  happent, and not at JFrame initialization.

Comment: Add the listener to the frame AFTER the frame is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way to go-

1. Define a boolean flag to indicate if the component is shown, default to false
2. Override componentShown() and set this flag to true, this gets called when the frame is made visible
3. In componentResized() check if componentShown flag is set, only then do something

Something like this-

```
    private boolean componentShown = false; // instance variable

    someJFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            if(componentShown) {
               System.out.println("Component RESIZED");
            }  
        }

        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            componentShown = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, worked beautifully. So, my guess is that componentResized is called before componentShown.